# IdentityServer4 - Is there a way to silently authenticate user as part of the authorization code flow?

Tags: identityserver4

My scenario is that there is only one user for a client and that user will be used to fetch/create the API data. I want to use authorization code flow (or whichever suits?) and silently authenticate that one user and generate id_token and access token. My client don't want the login screen to authenticate (perhaps they already have user authenticated in their app) for now as there is only going to be one user.

How will this be achieved and using what grant_type ? Or it there a way to Auto login user using their username and password?

Comment: In this case IdentityServer4 may not be the tool to use. Whitelisting may be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have their `username` and `password` you can use the [Token Endpoint](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints/token.html):

> POST /connect/token
>
> client_id=yourclientid& client_secret=yourclientsecret&
> grant_type=password&
> username=yourusername&password=yourusernamespassword

You can use [Identity Model](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/token.html) to help you make the token request:

```
var response = await client.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordTokenRequest
{
    Address = "https://demo.identityserver.io/connect/token",

    ClientId = "yourclientid",
    ClientSecret = "yourclientsecret",
    UserName = "yourusername",
    Password = "yourusernamespassword"
});
```

Comment: what will be the grant type for this client in this case?  can I set it to be authorisation code and still pass password grant type ?

Comment: It'd be client credentials or resource owner password for this sort of back channel flow. If it's a machine-to-machine type integration then client credentials is the best fit.

Comment: The client is mobile app in this case. Is client credentials or resource owner password be okay?